# return a powershell cmd to excel cell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to create some code for a button to return a portion of a PowerShell command to a target cell. I only want the first 2 characters of the status ("Ru" for running or "ST" for Stopped) to go into the cell.

The PowerShell cmdlet I want to use is:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> get-service -Name browser

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  browser            Computer Browser
```

I don't know how I can parse the returned value to get just the 2 characters.
I've started with this code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim retval As String
retval = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> 'get-service' -Name browser")
End Sub
```

I get a runtime error "`file not found`", so I'm guessing at the very least my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your Shell command is broken, you pass a prompt instead of the path to an executable. can't test at the moment, but this should work:

```
Sub Button2_Click() 
  Dim retval As String 
  retval = Left(Shell("powershell -command '(get-service -Name browser).Status'"),2) 
End Sub
```

**Edit** The above scripts works, but as intended with the shell function it returns only the pid of the executed command
The WshShellExec function can do what you want, but it has an annoying flicker of the running powershell window.

```
Sub Button2_Click() 
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("powershell -command ""(get-service -Name browser).Status""")
    retval = Left(WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you LotPings,

Comment: Thank you LotPings,
I must admit, I looked at that code many times and did not see that it was incomplete. So, your suggestion executed OK, but it seems to return 2  numbers? I was expecting either 2 chars 'RU' or 'ST'. Also, each subsequent execution (I have a button coded with the execution string) returns a different number. I'm not sure what those numbers represent.any Ideas?

Comment: @Jimf2 Edited my answer.

Comment: LotPings,This works good. I don't mind the flicker. I tried imbedding another command to get another result and I get a syntax error.

Comment: So when your question is answered I'd be glad if you would check my answer. To your unknown changes I can't say anything. To get more attention it would be better to make up a new question.

Comment: LotPings, The "WshShell" command worked great. I don't mind the flicker to get the result.
This is what the code looks like that I'm trying:
        Sub Button2_Click() 
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("powershell -command ""(get-adcomputer -Filter 'name -Like "*49990"' -properties "name" -SearchBase "OU=B03,OU=workstations,DC=trans,DC=dal,DC=com" |Select name""")
        retval = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
        Range("C5").Value = MID(retval, 9,2)
        End Sub

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems I cannot figure out what needs double quotes in the command.

Comment: Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("powershell -command ""(get-adcomputer -Filter 'name -Like "*49990"' -properties "name" -SearchBase "OU=B03,OU=workstations,DC=trans,DC=dal,DC=com" |Select name""")